# Swift 3 UICollectionView weird spacing between cells

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, spacing, flowlayout

I wanted to create a simple UICollectionView ; one cell which has one label. The cell and label width should increase / decrease based on the width of the text. The spacing between the labels should be 1.

I tried to do that with the following code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let ab =  items[indexPath.item] --> The string of the cell
    var width1 = StringToWidth(SomeString: ab) // Calculate the width of the text
    width1 = width1 * 1.1 // Looks better

    return CGSize(width: width1, height: 50)
}

//Lines
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 1
}

// Spaces
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 1
}
```

In the storyboard I set min spacing to 0 of the collection view.

The result:

[image]

I thought I must have done something wrong I went to google and found 
[CellSizeToFitLabel](https://github.com/jeremiah-de/CellSizeToFitLabel)

This however changes the height of the cell instead of the width(it works btw). So I changed the static preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 50 to StringToWidth(SomeString: label.text!)

I expected this to work , however this was the result :
[image]

I would love to know why it spaces like that and how to fix it

Comment: Are you targeting iOS10+ or supporting iOS9 ? if so you can use UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize, and return that in sizeForItem

Comment: Yes , I'm targeting iOS10+ will surely try that , thanks!

Comment: I cannot get it to work , do you have an example / demo that would really be appreciated

Comment: remember to set your flowLayouts minimumLineSpacing and minimumInterItemSpace